# Assigning a ClickListener to a button in a second layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm working on a project for an app (android) and I'm using `Android Studio` for my company. The problem is I'm fairy new in this kind of programming. I came from `Windows VB` and I'm afraid that working in `Android Java` is not quite that easy.

I already made a basic interface for my app and chose to made a `FrameLayout` based application (just like `Panels` in `VB`). So far so good.

However I'm having troubles assigning a `ClickListener` to a `Button` on `MainActivity` class because that `Button` isn't located at the `activity_main.xml` file. Let me show you what I got so far:

Fist I created a `Button` and a `FrameLayout` on `activity_main.xml` file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/CO001"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/campo007_left"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/campo007_top"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/campo007_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/campo007_height"
    android:text="@string/co001"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FR001"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/field006_l"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/field006_t"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/field006_w"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/field006_h"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Then, on `MainActivity.java` inside `onCreate` method, I declared the button as `bt001`, and assigned it a `setOnClickListener` method to show, on that `FrameLayout` the contents of another `.xml` file (`fr001.xml`):

```
Button bt001 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CO001);
bt001.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        FrameLayout fr001 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FR001);
        fr001.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fr001.removeAllViews();
        View frcont = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fr001, null);
        fr001.addView(frcont);}});
```

This work perfectly fine. Almost like `Visual Basic`. However, on `fr001.xml`, I have another button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/FR001CO001"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="432dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:text="@string/ModA"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

When I tried to assign a `setOnClickListener` method to it, the application crashes. I think it's because the second `.xml` file is not "loaded" on `MainActivity` or something like it...

I already tried to link the second `.xml` file to another activity and starting it once you click on `CO001` button, but on this scenario, the second `.xml` appears on the original `FrameLayout` and starts on the application screen, and I don't want that.

I'm positive this issue has a simple solution (or maybe not!!). Can you help me with this?? Any help will be very appreciated. And, as always, thank you all in advance.

Comment: This is simple if you want to show second button in your main_activity then you have to either include or write that xml code in your activity_main.xml file. Or you can make another activity and create another xml layout file and put that button into it.

Comment: Can I have a third option? The two solutions you gave me are exactly what I didn't want to do...

Comment: can I ask where is your second button exactly ? Inside that frameLayout you mentioned or somewhere else ?

Comment: It's inside the `FrameLayout` once I click the first button. It is declared on the second `.xml` file.

Comment: If you are using it in framelayout then you can access it easily. But I don't understand what exactly you are doing here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the button like that:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr001, null); 
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.FR001CO001);
```

Comment: I can get the button... What I can't do is assign the `onClickListener` method to it.

Comment: I did it now and my code lets me assign the `onClickListener` on the `Button`, you should be able to do it. If you can't, you could try changing the view: `View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fr001, null);`